# Why is read_csv so much slower to parse dates than to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I am using jupyter notebook and reading a .csv file with pandas read_csv. When using the following code, it takes a reeeeeeeally long time (more than 10 minutes). The dataset has 70821 entries.

```
    [Input]
    df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", parse_dates=[0])
    df.head()
    
    [Output]
    created_at  field1  field2
    2022-09-16T22:53:19+07:00   100.0   NaN
    2022-09-16T22:54:46+07:00   100.0   NaN
    2022-09-16T22:56:14+07:00   100.0   NaN
    2022-09-16T23:02:01+07:00   100.0   NaN
    2022-09-16T23:03:28+07:00   100.0   NaN
```

If I just use `parse_dates=True` it will not detect the date and keep it as object.

If I read the dataset without `parse_dates` it goes much faster like I would expect it (~1 second).
When I then use a seperate line of code to parse the date like

```
df["created_at"]=pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
```

it goes faster than using `parse_dates` in read_csv but still takes couple of minutes (around 3 minutes).

Using the following

```
df["created_at"]=pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
```

or with the `T` in the format string

```
df["created_at"]=pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

or

```
df["created_at"]=pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

does not increase the speed (still around 3 minutes)

So my questions are the following:

1. Why is the slowest way to parse the date directly with read_csv?
2. Why is the way with `pd.to_datetime` faster and
3. Why does something like `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"` or `infer_datetime_format=True` not speed up the process
4. And finally how do I do it in a better way? If I read the file once and parsed it to datetime, what would be the best way to write it back to a csv file so I don't have to go through this process all over again? I assume I have to write a function and manually change every entry to a better formatted date?

Can someone help me figuring out why those different approaches take such a different amount of time and how I speed up e.g. with something I tried in 3.?
Thanks a lot.

---

EDIT:

I tried now to manually adjust the date format and see, where it causes trouble. Turns out, when I delete `+07:00` in the date string, it is fast (~500 ms).

Under this following link I uploaded to csv files. `example1` is the file with the problematic datetime format. In `example2_no_timezone` I deleted in every entry the `+07:00` part which makes the parsing fast again (expected behaviour).

[Folder with two example datasets](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhMadgxHtPSBg6EuAY0mopdmwCtsPw?e=RerSd6)

The questions above do remain sadly.

1. Why is pandas not able to read the original date string in an appropriate time
2. Why is to_datetime faster (but still too slow with the original dataset
3. How do I fix this without changing the format in the original dataset (e.g., with means of `to_datetime` and providing `format=...`)

Comment: what's the datetime format in your input .csv ?

Comment: I read a file with 217,200 records (34 columns, 126Mb) in 0.69s with the same code (my first col is a datetime).

Comment: @FObersteiner the format is in the the first output `2022-09-16T22:53:19+07:00`. I tried to speed this up with matching the format string `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"` but without success.

Comment: @Corralien Yes I also think my times are really odd/high. My laptop is not the fastest but definitely not THAT slow

Comment: your format is missing a T; `format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"`. Also, it might be beneficial to convert to UTC by setting keyword `utc=True`. If you need the datetime to be in a certain time zone, set it afterwards using `.dt.tz_convert("desired-tz-name")`

Comment: @FObersteiner thanks for the suggestion. I just tried `df["created_at"]=pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")` but CPU time was again 3:14 minutes

Comment: That's definitely too long for a < 100k lines csv. Anything else between you and the file maybe, loading it from a server? Did you try with a simple Python script, I mean without the Jupyter NB, just a plain script which you call from a terminal?

Comment: @FObersteiner The file is located in the same folder. And I just also tried to use a plain text file script. But it has the same outcome (except maybe for a few seconds faster, but still around 3 minutes). I will try tomorrow to change the date format manually and see if that helps. So far I did never experience anything similar on the same machine with different dates.

Comment: Please try to make a [mre], or as close as possible. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). Maybe try moving the code and data to a different machine and seeing how it runs.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you. I edited the post and provide now two datasets that can be tested with the code snippets provided.